# Integration when the singular point is on the contour

Tags: reference-request

Suppose $f(z)$ is a analytic function inside and on the contour $|m|=1$, by using Residue Theorem, $\int_{|m|=\rho}\frac{f(z)}{z-1}dz=2\pi f(1)$ for any $\rho>1$, but how to calculate the integration $\int_{|m|=1}\frac{f(z)}{z-1}dz$? It seems that the answer is $\pi f(1)$, but how to prove it. Are there any reference?

Comment: The magic words are "Cauchy principal value"

Answer (score 2):

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value and http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/stcs/courses/fcm/handouts/cauchy_principal_value.pdf.